# How to disable <input> submit but not typing

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've got this `<input>` that I want to be able to enter stuff in, but not submit, because I already have a button that will be submitting it to a form handler.

```
    <form name="form">
    <input id="JSinp" type="email" name="Com" method="post"
    autocomplete="off" required autofocus>                                                                                   
    </form>
    <button onclick="exec()" id="evalbutton">Submit</button>

    <script>
    function exec() {
    var Com = document.forms["form"] ["Com"].value;
    eval(Com);
    }
```

The id's are solely for styling purposes. Currently, when I press enter on the `<input>` it shows up in the URL and goes through the whole posting refresh and whatever. That's another thing. When using `method="post"` isn't it not supposed to show up in the URL bar? This might just be a bug in my browser but any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I just replaced the button with this: 
`<input type="submit" onclick="exec()" id="evalbutton" value="Submit">`
and that works. 
*But any help with the `method="post"` would be a big help.*

Comment: why do you have to use method="post" and  submit="exec()" on the input ?

Comment: @SnakeFoot submit="exec()" was a mistake, sorry about that. The reason I want to use method="post" is because it looks neater :) . Sorry but that's just what I want to do.

Comment: insert method="post" on the form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a few tips:

- the `method="post"` belongs on the `form` tag
- the `onsubmit="exec()"` belongs on the `form` tag as well
- Never, *never* use `eval`

second, if you to prevent the form to submit when someone presses enter (which submits the form by default), listen for a keydown. And if it's enter, prevent the form to submit.

https://jsfiddle.net/ue3knhLz/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent that event from happening by skipping the enter key.

```
document.getElementById('JSinp').addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  var KEYCODE_ENTER = 13;
  if (event.which == KEYCODE_ENTER)
    event.preventDefault();
});
```